# Python 2.7 : Import a module situated in a subdirectory from a different subdirectory

Tags: python-2.7, module

Here's my code configuration:

```
__init__py
./module_1/foo.py
./module_1/__init__.py
./module_2/bar.py
./module_2/__init__.py
```

My goal is to be able to import the **foo** module from **bar.py**, but I'm getting quite confused on how to do it.

Something such as:

```
from ..module_1.foo import *
```

Will raise the following error:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

EDIT:

Ideally I'd like to be able to run my script in the following fashion:

> python ./module1/foo.py

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown how you are invoking the script, but you need to ensure that your scripts are actually packages in your python path. That's basically what the error message is telling you, you were trying to import a "non-package". You probably don't have your top-level in the python path. For example ...

If your top-level module is called **app** and your configuration is

```
<path-to-app>/app/__init__py
<path-to-app>/app/module_1/foo.py
<path-to-app>/app/module_1/__init__.py
<path-to-app>/app/module_2/bar.py
<path-to-app>/app/module_2/__init__.py
```

You can run your script as follows.

```
cd <path-to-app>
PYTHONPATH=$PWD python -m app.module_2.bar
```

Works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just updated the question with more details, but I'd bet that playing around with the python path is the way to go... Thanks.